# VBA Vlook-up of Photo

Tags: excel, vlookup

I am new in excel so please help me come up with an automated requisition form.

I have 15,000 SKU and I need to have a request form with picture.

I want it to be vlook up type that when I input an SKU, the pictures from Sheet 2 (data masterfile) will show on sheet 1 (printable requisition form), as well as the details of the particular SKU (locator & description).

I have tried some formulas I found on google but there are lots of complicated formulas and the excel crashes and lags. Even if I lower the resolution of the pictures, it still crashes. Please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: Create a simple test file with only 5-10 SKUs and 5-10 photos. Then start with some simple formulas that will work. Gradually add more "special" cases for the SKUs and photos and see what questions you have with your formulas. When you encounter those specific problems, come back and ask your question and show us what you've done so we can understand more clearly what you want to do.

Comment: I already tried it using basic formulas and name range for the picture but my file slows down when I add few more SKUs, pictures and details. Like it hangs when I tried to print it and took almost 1 minute before it actually prints. Same with saving the file. I am wondering if I can find a VBA code for this, the processing will be faster and will not hang. Please help me. I have a sample file not sure how can I post it here.